# Can DMARC apply to email already received?

Tags: spam, spf, dmarc

We have a domain that has been "ruined" by spammers, using it's reputation for sending spam mails.

We're moving to a different domain and would like the previous domain to become a "death trap"; marking any new mail using the domain for `from:`, `replyto:` or `bounce:` as spam.

Setting up DMARC and SPF to reject all emails is easy, but how will this affect emails already received? Are DMARC records ever re-checked after already having been checked once?

Answer (score 1):

Email authentication is checked before the email arrives. I think this [image maps it out well](https://dmarc.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DMARC_author-to-recipient_flow.jpg). I don't think you're in danger of having emails checked retroactively. Once an email has run the gauntlet, it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Neil is correct, +1.

I just wanted to make you aware that SPF has nothing to do with the `from:`, `reply-to:` or `bounce:`. It focuses on the `return-path:`, which you might be referring to as the `bounce:`?  DMARC applies to the `from:`.

So if someone uses the domain in `reply-to:` unfortunately their's nothing you can do about it.

If someone was able to spam through your old domain, they would be able to do it to the new domain, unless you were able to find the vulnerability and plug it.